# How to expose every name in sub-module in __init__.py of a package?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I defined a package that include a dynamically growing set of modules:

```
- mypackage
    - __init__.py
    - module1.py
    - module2.py
    - module3.py
    ... many more .py files will be added
```

I could expose every name in every module in `__init__.py` like this:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
from module3 import *
```

Now when I `import mypackage` in client code, I get all the names defined in the sub-modules:

```
# suppose funcA is defined in module1, class B is defined in module2
import mypackage
mypackage.funcA() # call module1.funcA
b = mypackage.B() # module2.B
```

The problem is, I could define many new modules in mypackage, and I don't want to add an extra line `from modulex import *` to `__init__.py`, every time I add a new module to the package.

What is the best way to dynamically export names in all submodules?

Comment: maybe `eval()` on the directory contents?

Comment: Neither enumerating what you're importing nor where you're importing from is gonna make it that much harder to track down bugs and just be able to read, just my 2 cents

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 the solution is straightforward using `importlib` and `pkgutil`.

Placing the following code in `__init__.py` is the same typing `from submodule import *` for all submodules (even nested ones).

```
import importlib
import pkgutil

for mod_info in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__, __name__ + '.'):
    mod = importlib.import_module(mod_info.name)

    # Emulate `from mod import *`
    try:
        names = mod.__dict__['__all__']
    except KeyError:
        names = [k for k in mod.__dict__ if not k.startswith('_')]

    globals().update({k: getattr(mod, k) for k in names})
```

If you only want to include immediate submodules (e.g. `pkg.mod` but not `pkg.mod.submod`), replace `walk_packages` with `iter_modules`.

I emulated `from mod import *` based on this answer: [How to do from module import * using importlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059267/how-to-do-from-module-import-using-importlib?rq=1)

Comment: Great tip for updating `globals` automatically! In order to have the imports work as the OP requested, you also need to append to `__all__` like other answers have shown

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean:

but if i've understood correctly - do this in your `__init__.py` file.

```
import os

__all__ = []

for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module != '__init__.py' and module[-3:] == '.py':
        __all__.append(module[:-3])
```

You're adding all files in the same package into the `__all__`

Comment: But this doesn't import the submodules. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear, I have updated the question.

Comment: This solution will let you do this `from myPackage import module1` and then `module1.funcA()`. And you can add any number of modules into the package without changing `__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding module names to `__all__` will not always serve the purpose. I came across such an issue and also required them to be imported in addition to adding them to `__all__`. This is the code I came up with to make it work in my case. I didn't have any sub packages, so this code works only at the top level.

```
modules = glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/*.py')
__all__ = []
for mod in modules:
  if not str(mod).endswith('__init__.py'):
    package_prefix = __name__ + '.'
    module_name = str(mod)[str(mod).rfind('\\') + 1:-3]
    __all__.append(module_name)
    __import__(package_prefix + module_name, globals(), locals(), [''])
```